# program freezes after calling qApp.quit() due to lambda

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

I'm making this really basic PyQt5 application and after using a lambda function it freezes after calling qApp.quit(). This is a big part of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenu, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):

        # Creamos un status bar para que muestre las etiquetas
        self.statusBar()
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Barra de tareas')

        # Creamos un menú simple
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        
        # Creamos una entrada del menú y la asociamos al menú simple creado
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Archivo')
        vistaMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Ver')
        
        # Creamos una acción del menú, le asociamos un icono y un nombre, donde la
        # letra a la que le sigue el símbolo & estará subrallada
        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Salir', self)
        
        # Le asociamos un 'atajo'. No solo mostrará este atajo al lado de la etiqueta,
        # sino que se hará efectivo
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        
        # Le asociamos a la entrada un etiqueta que se mostrará en el status bar de la aplicación
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Salir de la aplicación')
        
        verToolBar = QAction('&Barra de tareas', self, checkable=True)
        verToolBar.setChecked(True)
        
        # Creamos un submenú que contendrá sus propias acciones
        ayudaMenu = QMenu('&Ayuda', self)
        ayudaMenu.setIcon(QIcon('ayuda.png'))

        #Creamos una acción para el submenú
        infoAct = QAction(QIcon('information.png'), '&Información', self)
        infoAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        infoAct.setStatusTip('Información del programa')
        
        
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(infoAct)
        
        # Añadimos las acciones creadas anteriormente a la entrada del menú
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)
        ayudaMenu.addAction(infoAct)
        fileMenu.addMenu(ayudaMenu)
        vistaMenu.addAction(verToolBar)   
        
        # Asociamos una señal a esa entrada. En este caso, la señal de cierre de programa.
        # Tanto la sentencia comentada como la que no hacen lo mismo. Hay varias formas de llamar
        # a quit():
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        menubar.hovered.connect(lambda: self.setCheck(verToolBar))
        
        #exitAct.triggered.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
        infoAct.triggered.connect(self.mostrarMensaje)
        verToolBar.triggered.connect(self.verBarraTareas)
        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Aplicación simple')
        self.show()
        
    def setCheck(self, verToolBar):
        if(self.toolbar.isHidden()):
            verToolBar.setChecked(False)
                
        else:
            verToolBar.setChecked(True)
    
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is exactly at this line:

```
menubar.hovered.connect(lambda: self.setCheck(verToolBar))
```

Since when I comment it the program exits naturally. Somehow using lambda prevents the program from closing after killing the main loop, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem with PyQt5 5.15.4 on Linux. Are you using any IDE or special environment to run your code?

Comment: I'm using Spyder from Anaconda, I'll try running it from terminal. You're right, running it from terminal works just fine. How weird, I've restarted both Spyder and Anaconda but the problem remains.

Comment: In any case, is that connection intended to just toggle the action for the toolbar, showing it checked if the toolbar is visible and unchecked if it's not?

Comment: Exactly. Using a lambda function is the only way I could figure to make this happen. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: QMainWindow has [`createPopupMenu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#createPopupMenu) which automatically returns a menu with actions for all child toolbars/dock widgets, and both QDockWidget and QToolBar provide their own `toggleViewAction()` which returns the same individual actions, and they're always updated. Also, using the `hover` signal to update a menu is not good, as it calls the function even when not required, a better choice is to do everything before the menu is shown: use `vistaMenu.aboutToShow.connect(self.someFunction)` and implement anything you need in `someFunction`

Comment: I was aware that using hover wasn't optimal but I really couldn't come up with any other way to carry this out haha. Thanks for the advice, I'll try using those methods.